# How to http post byte array or string as file in C#

Tags: c#, post, file-upload, webclient

I need to post xml string as file. Here is my code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadData(@"http://example.com/upload.php",
                      Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SerializeToXml(entity)));
}
```

It successfully post data, but data is not recognized by server as uploaded file.

I need it to work similar to this

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadFile(@"http://example.com/upload.php", @"C:\entity.xml");
}
```

How can I achieve this without saving xml to file system?

Comment: Why are you against using file system? Create temp file, Upload, then delete the file. If there is no overload of `UploadFile` which takes a stream, you are stuck with creating temp file.

Comment: I believe UploadData might leave out some information in the header and post data. It uploads the bytes as plain bytes. You probably need to set some headers for mime etc. -- I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it using `HttpClient`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("Upload----" + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    {
        using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(SerializeToXml(p)))
        {
            StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
            streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            content.Add(streamContent, "file", "post.xml");

            using (var message = client.PostAsync("http://example.com/upload.php", content).Result)
            {
                string response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string str)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    return new MemoryStream(byteArray);
}
```